How to prompt an EOA to sign a Solana transaction from Telegram App
I am wondering if it is possible to have a user sign a transaction directly from Telegram?
For example, to max approve the game tokens to be moved by an escrow account, is it possible to prompt a users phantom/solflare wallet directly from telegram, so that the users wallets open up with the proposed transaction?
All examples ive seen of telegram prompting users for signatures is either when a user imports their secret key into the telegram app or a user has created a wallet on a telegram app. I am dealing with users EOA (externally owned account) and not imported secret keys or generated user wallets in app.

I don't think this is currently possible to have a prompt on the user's extension to sign a transaction from Telegram.
Your best bet as you've noted is importing the user's secret key into your bot.
But, there might be hope if Solana Blinks become supported on Telegram which is the
